# Language switcher in cakephp from english to germen(de) and german(de) to english

Tags: cakephp

I want to switch between two language English and Germen(de) is any tool in cakePhp which it do for me.

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can localize your php with cakephp: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html

Comment: I did not get this example have you any example for this

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't, what did you not understand?